# An open data reader

Tags: c#

i recieve this message when i run the action: "There is already an open DataReader associated with this Command which must be closed first."

my code is:public void UpdatePoints(string rightScore, string rightWinner)
    {

```
    cmd.CommandText = "select * from Users_Details";
    cmd.Connection = connection;
    connection.Open();
    rdr = cmd.ExecuteReader();

    while (rdr.Read())
    {

        int points=0;
        string sql;
        string hisScore = (string)rdr["lastbetscore"];
        string hisWinner = (string)rdr["lastbetwinner"];
        if (rightScore == hisScore)
            points = points + 30;
        if (rightWinner == hisWinner)
        {
            points = points + 20;
        }

        sql = "update Users_Details set lastgame_points='" + points + "', gamesplayed='" + ((int)rdr["gamesplayed"] + 1) + "',currentpoints='" + ((int)rdr["currentpoints"] + points) + "',pointsPG='" + (((int)rdr["currentpoints"] + points) / ((int)rdr["gamesplayed"] + 1)) + "' where username='" + (string)rdr["username"] + "'";
        cmd.CommandText = sql;
        cmd.ExecuteScalar();
    }
    rdr.Close();
    connection.Close();
}
```

Answer (score 3):

The error message is pretty specific about what you doing wrong. You cannot reuse the command or the connection for another command **while** you're reading data from it. You must firstly read all the data to some `List` or another data structure and then update db with each element of this `List`.

Also, consider to execute your statements in transaction

```
var transaction = connection.BeginTransaction(); 
... 
transaction.Commit();
```

This will speed up your updates since transaction will be created and commited only once but other way transaction will be created implicitely on **each** update

Comment: Now it prints "There is already an open DataReader associated with this Connection which must be closed first." ? Instead of "Command"?

Comment: My first answer was wrong, because you cannot reuse not only the command but the connection also. Please, see the corrected answer.

Comment: No, it is the same message

Comment: OK, Thanks I will try it

Answer (score 0):

You should create a new Command instance instead of reusing the old one here:

```
sql = "update Users_Details set lastgame_points='" + points + "', gamesplayed='" + ((int)rdr["gamesplayed"] + 1) + "',currentpoints='" + ((int)rdr["currentpoints"] + points) + "',pointsPG='" + (((int)rdr["currentpoints"] + points) / ((int)rdr["gamesplayed"] + 1)) + "' where username='" + (string)rdr["username"] + "'";
cmd.CommandText = sql;
cmd.ExecuteScalar();
```

In addition, read up on command parameters, formatting the sql string yourself opens you up to SQL injection attacks.